# how to remove Duplicate meta for each page breaks in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

google crawler found many Duplicate meta descriptions and title tags in my web, like these :

/tag/طراحی-دکوراسیون-مغازه/687-طراحی-داخلی-گل-فروشی

/tag/طراحی-دکوراسیون-مغازه/687-طراحی-داخلی-گل-فروشی?showall=&limitstart=

/tag/طراحی-دکوراسیون-مغازه/687-طراحی-داخلی-گل-فروشی?showall=1

Obviously the crawler found each page breaks as same meta or title tag!!! how can i fix this?

my joomla version is 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

This is an usual Seo problem in Joomla! You have three ways:

1 - Disable the filter button from Tag Administrator

2 - Delete the filter button from one or more php file here: components/com_tags/views/tag (and tags)

3 - Open the robot.txt inside root, to ask to search engine to don't consider the TAG folder, but if you are choosing the tag module maybe it's because you want to earn positions really in there.

Comment: How can i fix this by editing router.php in com_context ?

Comment: Yes.I think that you are watching on Content component ( com_content ), not com_context. If you're using this component, you have to know that it is not a default component. It 's a third part component (external). In any case I don't know if deleting the function in route.php , you could solve your problem.